# Is it possible to defer member initialization to the constructor body?

Tags: c++, oop, boost, constructor, initialization

I have a class with an object as a member which doesn't have a default constructor. I'd like to initialize this member in the constructor, but it seems that in C++ I can't do that. Here is the class:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

template<class T>
class udp_sock
{
    public:
        udp_sock(std::string host, unsigned short port);
    private:
        boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
        udp::socket _sock;
        boost::array<T,256> _buf;
};

template<class T>
udp_sock<T>::udp_sock(std::string host = "localhost",
  unsigned short port = 50000)
{
    udp::resolver res(_io_service);
    udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), host, "spec");
    udp::endpoint ep = *res.resolve(query);
    ep.port(port);
    _sock(_io_service, ep);
}
```

The compiler tells me basically that it can't find a default constructor for udp::socket and by my research I understood that C++ implicitly initializes every member before calling the constructor. Is there any way to do it the way I wanted to do it, or is it too "Java-oriented" and not feasible in C++?

I worked around the problem by defining my constructor like this:

```
template<class T>
udp_sock<T>::udp_sock(std::string host = "localhost",
  unsigned short port = 50000) : _sock(_io_service)
{
    udp::resolver res(_io_service);
    udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), host, "spec");
    udp::endpoint ep = *res.resolve(query);
    ep.port(port);
    _sock.bind(ep);
}
```

So my question is more out of curiosity and to better understand OOP in C++

Comment: Alternatively you may be able to deport the computation occurring in the body in an outside function: `udp_sock(): _sock(myfunc()) {}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define a constructor, you have 2 ways to "initialize" attributes:

- the initializer list
- the constructor body

If you do not explictly initialize one of the attributes in the initializer list, it is nonetheless initialized (by calling its default constructor) for you...

So in essence:

```
class Example
{
public:
  Example();
private:
  Bar mAttr;
};

// You write
Example::Example() {}

// The compiler understands
Example::Example(): mAttr() {}
```

And this of course fails if the underlying type does not have a Default Constructor.

There are various ways to defer this initialization. The "standard" way would be to use a pointer:

```
class Example { public: Example(); private: Bar* mAttr; };
```

However I prefer using [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) combined with suitable accessors:

```
class Example
{
public: Example();
private:
  Bar& accessAttr() { return *mAttr; }
  const Bar& getAttr() const { return *mAttr; }
  boost::Optional<Bar> mAttr;
};

Example::Example() { mAttr = Bar(42); }
```

Because Boost.Optional means that there is no overhead on the allocation and no overhead on the dereferencing (the object is created in place) and yet carries the correct semantic.

Comment: Thanks for the quick sample using boost::optional, it saved me the time needed to read the documentation just to understand if it could help me or not. This is exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: Don't hesitate to read it when you find some time. It's actually quite short as it's a simple utility, but there are some options (like in-place factory to build the object) that are worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's one possible use case for [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Beat me to it while I was writing my examples :p It's my preferred way to deal with this case.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was looking for, but I'm choosing Matthieu's answer since he also provided a simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it's preferable to initialize members in the initializer list, rather than the body of the constructor, so in fact you might consider putting other members in the initialization list

If you're thinking about creating a constructor that other ctors call, that's not available til c++0x  (see [inheriting constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2540.htm))

Answer (score 0):

If it's to initialize a variable during construction in a class's constructor the right way is:

```
template<class T>
udp_sock<T>::udp_sock(std::string host = "localhost", unsigned short port = 50000)
    :res(_io_service)
    ,query(udp::v4(), host, "spec")
    ,ep(*res.resolve(query))
    ,_sock(_io_service, ep)
{
}
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that 'res', 'query' and 'ep' should be part of the class. Another crude method (without having _sock as a pointer) is as given below:

```
template<class T>
udp_sock<T>::udp_sock(std::string host = "localhost", unsigned short port = 50000)
    :_sock(_io_service, udp::resolver(_io_service).resolve(udp::resolver::query(udp::v4(),host,"spec"))
{
}
```

Comment: But this requires making `res`, `query`, and `ep` class members and not local variables of the constructor, which changes the contents of his class and is not particularly elegant.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I've added that into the edit and added another constructor that doesn't need any of those variables to be a member variable. They are created at runtime and destroyed as soon as it's used. The main disadvantage of using this method is that an exception that occurs during construction will cause memory leak. The best method is to either use _sock as a pointer or a boost::scoped_ptr.

Comment: I thought about the second version on my own, but I found it to be not so elegant as I would like it to be, that's why I kept looking for better solutions.

Comment: You have to make a trade-off in this case (I believe). It's either you create an ugly line of code that would make rest of your code look elegant or make a 'looking good' piece of code and end up using a pointer.
Personally, I would go down the line of using a pointer because that's the 'correct' way of doing it. Your code would not leak memory (as mentioned in my previous comment) if it throws an exception inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is the correct way to do things.

You can also postpone the creation of the object by making is pointer (however it changes the code and data type):

```
std::auto_ptr<udp::socket> _sock;
```

And then in body:

```
_sock.reset(new udp::soket(_io_service, ep));
```

But I think that your "workaround" is rather correct solution then workaround.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same. But instead of std::auto_ptr i was going to suggest boost::scoped_ptr since he's already using boost libararies.

Comment: Pointers means heap usage overhead and screwed copy semantics... though `scoped_ptr` will at least expose the copy problems!

Comment: I just prefer using standard library where possible, especially when `scoped_ptr` is just "little bit" stripped `auto_ptr`. I never use one.

Comment: @Mattheiu, `io_service` is already non-copyable... So it does not meter. In any case such class *should* be defined as non-copyable.

Comment: I always try to propose generic solutions since this problem appears regularly :)

Comment: quite old answer already, but by now `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated. Maybe either the answer should get an update or the question be tagged as c++03. Came here for something else, so I don't know what would be best

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the `_sock` member into a [smart pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

template<class T>
class udp_sock
{
    public:
        udp_sock(std::string host, unsigned short port);
    private:
        boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
        boost::scoped_ptr<udp::socket> _sock_ptr;
        boost::array<T,256> _buf;
};

template<class T>
udp_sock<T>::udp_sock(std::string host = "localhost",
  unsigned short port = 50000)
{
    udp::resolver res(_io_service);
    udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), host, "spec");
    udp::endpoint ep = *res.resolve(query);
    ep.port(port);
    _sock_ptr.reset(new udp::socket(_io_service, ep));
}
```

Comment: This means heap allocation + problems of copy semantics. It's a lot of hurt.

Comment: Not so much in his case, since `boost::asio::io_service` is already non-copyable.

Comment: I thought about pointers too, but I wanted to avoid dealing with allocation/deallocation and all the potential problems linked with pointers. I try to avoid pointers unless they are the only solution or they provide clear speed advantages...

Answer (score 0):

Another option in this case is to work around the issue by creating a static function to build ep:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

template<class T>
class udp_sock
{
    public:
        udp_sock(std::string host, unsigned short port);
    private:
        static udp::endpoint build_ep(const std::string &host,
          unsigned short port, boost::asio::io_service &io_service);

        boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
        udp::socket _sock;
        boost::array<T,256> _buf;
};

template<class T>
udp::endpoint udp_sock<T>::build_ep(const std::string &host,
  unsigned short port, boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
{
    udp::resolver res(io_service);
    udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), host, "spec");
    udp::endpoint ep = *res.resolve(query);
    ep.port(port);
    return ep;
}

template<class T>
udp_sock<T>::udp_sock(std::string host = "localhost",
  unsigned short port = 50000)
    : _sock(_io_service, build_ep(host, port, _io_service))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really ancient thread, but there is another possibility using an anonymous union. Let me first declare a helper class without a standard constructor, which will inform us about the moment of constructor and destructor calling:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Embedded
{
    Embedded(const char* init_name)
    : name(init_name)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor of Embedded: " << name << std::endl;
    }

    ~Embedded()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor of Embedded: " << name << std::endl;
    }

    std::string name;
};
```

Now let us embed three different objects of this class in another class. One is placed inside a union (which won't be automatically initialized). For this object, constructor and destructor must be manually called (using placement new). This is possible at any position in the code.

```cpp
struct Demo
{
    Embedded object_1 {"object_1"};
    Embedded object_2;

    union   // members won't be automatically constructed
    {
        Embedded object_3;  // don't use standard initializer (as for object_1)
    };

    Demo()
    : object_2("object_2")
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor of Demo" << std::endl;
        new (&object_3) Embedded ("object_3");
    }

    ~Demo()
    {
        object_3.~Embedded();
        std::cout << "Destructor of Demo" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Finally, use the Demo class in its own scope:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::cout << "main() start" << std::endl;

    {
        Demo demo;
        std::cout << "demo created" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "main() end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see from the output, the constructor is deferred.

```
main() start
Constructor of Embedded: object_1
Constructor of Embedded: object_2
Constructor of Demo
Constructor of Embedded: object_3
demo created
Destructor of Embedded: object_3
Destructor of Demo
Destructor of Embedded: object_2
Destructor of Embedded: object_1
main() end
```

So you can exactly define the moment of the deferred constructor call. The downside is, that you also have to manually call the destructor or really bad things can happen.