# More control over construction of member objects in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have a couple of classes in which I need more control over member construction than is provided through initialization lists.

In one class, I need the ability to retry the construction of a member with different arguments if the original construction throws.

In a second class, I need to pass the address of the member object to another function which will in turn call the constructor (via placement new). The problem here is that the function is a black box and I don't know what it will pass to the constructor.

In both cases, it is a requirement that the member object is held in the containing object, not dynamically allocated.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

### Edit

I noticed the question "[Is it possible to defer member initialization to the constructor body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464296/is-it-possible-to-defer-member-initialization-to-the-constructor-body)", which recommended boost::optional. This didn't quite solve my problem for a couple of reasons. First, I don't want to delay initialization, just have more control over it. Second, boost::optional stores an extra bool to indicate whether the object is initialized, which is not needed in my case. It did, however, get me thinking, and I came up with the solution I have posted below.

Comment: What's wrong with placing code in the constructor body?

Comment: @Jon: some objects cannot be modified once created, or assign differently than they construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the following class:

```
#include <type_traits> // Or <boost/type_traits.hpp>
template <typename Ty>
class manually_constructed
{
public:
   template <typename T>
   manually_constructed(T construct_func) {
      construct_func(static_cast<Ty*>(static_cast<void*>(&data)));
   }
   ~manually_constructed() {
      static_cast<Ty*>(static_cast<void*>(&data))->~Ty();
   }
   Ty& operator*() {
      return *static_cast<Ty*>(static_cast<void*>(&data));
   }
   Ty* operator->() {
      return static_cast<Ty*>(static_cast<void*>(&data));
   }
private:
   // Replace 'std' with 'boost' if your standard library doesn't support
   // type_traits, yet.
   std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Ty), std::alignment_of<Ty>::value>::type data;
};
```

Then, in my class, I can have a member such as `manually_constructed<OtherClass> object` and a private static method such as:

```
static void construct_object(OtherClass *p) {
   try {
      new(p) OtherClass(/* Risky arguments */);
   } catch(...) {
      new(p) OtherClass(/* Fallback arguments */);
   }
}
```

Finally, in my initializer list, I can have `object(construct_object)`.

With this solution, all member objects are stored within the containing object, there is no additional space overhead, all member objects are constructed in the correct order, and manually constructed objects will be destructed automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "retry" construction via a constructor alone.  You can swallow/handle an exception caused within your constructor using try/catch, and continue to populate the object if code inside the constructor fails though (using simple assignments).

If your initialization list throws, you're... screwed? though - nothing in your initialization list should throw.  It's executed prior to your constructor body and you have no control over exceptions thrown in it.

If you really need to retry construction with different parameters, wrap your construction in a **factory function** which can catch exceptions and try different options when they are received.

Moving on... when you call a constructor, you call a constructor.  The constructor itself creates the object on the heap or on the stack based on whether or not you used dynamic allocation mechanisms (mainly new).  You cannot decide within a constructor body itself to declare the object somewhere else, the decision has already been made.  You'll have to directly use placement new when you call new in order to achieve that.

Comment: What I meant by my last requirement is that the member object is stored within the my object, and not dynamically allocated during construction. I understand that I have no control over where my object is located from within its constructor. I edited the question slightly to hopefully clarify. (Without this requirement, I could just have a pointer as a member of my class, and things would be easy.)

Comment: I'd like to avoid requiring the use of a factory function, because that limits how my class can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Put apart construction and initialization procedure. I know it can sounds odd to you, but make construction of basic object in the initialization list and then try/catch to initialize it in the body of constructor with different sets of parameters with the separated init() method.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but, unfortunately, I have no control of the class of the contained object to pull it apart like that.

Comment: Do the objects allow copying? You can try to create temporary objects and then assign most successful of them to the member variable. Anyway you should isolate error prone and buggy process of subobject's creation from the constructor initialization list of the container. This list should contain no any exception sources.

Comment: Neither copying nor default construction, unfortunately.

Comment: @rkjnsn: The objects can't be copied?  That makes this quite tricky indeed.  You'll have to placement-new them into a buffer.